# Kinesis - cluster of consumers

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have a kinesis stream that is used to queue a task, say sending emails. I have a cluster of consumers that should read the queue, and then send emails.

In such a case, if a consumer reads one item from the queue, the other consumers should NOT read the same item; other I would send duplicate emails.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use KCL for Kinesis consumer applications. As you know, a record placed in the stream will be in a specific shard and by using KCL, you guarantee that only one consumer node (in the application) polls that shard. So there would be no risk of double listening the same shard (thus process the same record).

Secondly, Kinesis may be the wrong architecture for sending transactional stuff, like emails. It may be duplicated, or not even processed. It is not a reliable queue system.

For example, each record in stream contains an email but let's say while sending one of those got an error. What would you do? Would you put that one record to stream again, for retries? How many times will you retry? 
Also, Kinesis consumers poll records from the stream in bulk, so if one record is broken in a batch of records (`ProcessRecordsInput.getRecords`), the checkpoint for that batch (`ProcessRecordsInput.getCheckpointer`) might contain more than one item, including that broken record. So application restarts would risk you for double-processing.

I suggest using a queue based system (HornetQ, ActiveMQ etc.) would be better in your use case.